# How to test the order of mocked calls using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, easymock

It's easy enough in [EasyMock](http://easymock.org) to do:

```
EasyMock.expect(service.methodCall());
```

but I noticed that this does not test the order in which I execute the calls, which in a case that I am trying to test is very important. Is there anyway to do this with EasyMock?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `EasyMock.createStrictMock()` for creating a mock thats capable of checking the order of method calls.

http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html

(search for "Checking Method Call Order Between Mocks" in the above link for examples).

Comment: the page seems to have moved: http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-order

Answer (score 2):

If you need to test the order across different mocked objects, you can use `EasyMock.createStrictControl()` to create the mocks, run `replay()` & `verify()`.

This site has some handy sample code: [http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/mock-controls-with-easymock.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20140122023658/http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/mock-controls-with-easymock.html) (archive.org mirror)